# Weird "padding" in HTML action from POST header

Tags: java, html, http-post, forms

When I receive the POST header from this form in my server it has some weird padding added to it. Does anyone have an idea why it looks like this?
I don't have problems receiving other headers in my java server.

Server receive this:

```
POST /%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9Dindex.html%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D HTTP/1.1
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <body>

       <form method="post" action=”index.html”>
         Login name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
         Password: <input type=”password” name=”pass”><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

     <p>Register here.</p>

       </body>
     </html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should use `"` not `”`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action=”index.html”>
...
Password: <input type=”password” name=”pass”>
```

Note the different quotation marks.  You should be using ASCII character 34, `"`.  Your action attribute is using `”`, which is [Unicode code point 8221](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm).  That is the strange stuff being embedded in your post; you can see the E2 and 9D in there.

Answer (score 0):

just look at the the input quote in action not the right one should be action="index.html" also input password got the same problem